# Rails Heroku Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - db/csv_for_import/magazines.csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Hey guys I can run this Rake command (rake import_magazines) in development with no issues, but when I push to Heroku and run, I get: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - db/csv_for_import/magazines.csv 
Here's the code:

```
desc "Import magazine master from csv file"
task :import_magazines => [:environment] do
file = "db/csv_for_import/magazines.csv"

CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
```

It would seem to be something with the environment, I am very new to Rails so go gentle with me.

Comment: Is `db/csv_for_import/magazines.csv` committed to git? it is in the `.gitignore`? how are you trying to run this on Heroku? (what's the command?)

Comment: When I do a bash on Heroku, I can see magazines.csv.... When I run the command I run heroku run rake import_magazines.... as I mentioned it run flawlessly locally.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing exactly same issue. Could you please post the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full path:

```
file = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/db/csv_for_import/magazines.csv"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I think it is an answer to his question.

Comment: Yeah, but it's an awfull lazy one... If you improve it with some explaination on why this is working it'll be much better